# Is there a way to make a loading bar with the progress bar that actually has the value of the actual loading?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, loading

I'm trying to create a Progress Bar for the loading screen of my application, but I want the progress bar to show the *actual* loading progress. For most of my applications, the loading screen is specifically programed for the progress bar to move for approximately 2-3 seconds before it finishes and loads the main application. An example of what I'm talking about is the Grand Theft Auto loading screen. It takes around twenty seconds for me to load up the game in offline mode. The Grand Theft Auto loading screen takes a while because it's actually loading assets with the progress bar. I'm trying to create something similar to this where the time it takes for all the assets to load is the time on the progress bar.

I'm currently making this project in C#, and I have not really made an attempt yet as I would not know where to start. I would also like to mention that I've acknowledged if this were to be possible, loading screen will be rapid.

This is what I normally do in my loading screens:

```
Random rnd = new Random();

private async void loadingForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            percentageBarTime.Start();
        }


private async void percentageBarTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (percentageBar.Value <= 80)
            {
                percentageBar.Value += 5;
                await Task.Delay(percentageBarTimer.Interval);
                percentageBar.Value += 5;
                await Task.Delay(percentageBarTimer.Interval);
                percentageBar.Value += 5;
                await Task.Delay(percentageBarTimer.Interval);
                percentageBar.Value += 5;
                await Task.Delay(percentageBarTimer.Interval);
                percentageBarTimer.Stop();
            }
            else
            {
                percentageBar.Value += rnd.Next(1);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Well instead of updating the progress bar on a timer, do so in the code that loads the assets. We haven't seen any of that, so can't really tell how difficult that would be.

Comment: There are two ways of thinking, one is to load the file at one time, estimate a time according to the file size, and then control the progress displayed by the progress bar within this time; the difficulty here is that you need to obtain the computing performance of the computer and the need to load the file Size to estimate the time it takes to load.
The other is to use a [buffer array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffer?view=net-7.0) to read the file, according to the file size and buffer array Size, to control the progress displayed by the progress bar.